# Function to change text block in - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function

I'm developing a simple theme in Wordpress for a project, and I only need a function to allow me to change texts from different places in the page.

I already found how to create the admin panel but I only need the function to put in the `function.php` file.

Does anybody have any source I can study, or anything? Thank you.

Comment: What text are you referring to that you want to change?

Comment: In the content. I have 3 text blocks in my home page and I want to create a function that allows me to change it in the admin panel.